# SVG filters fuzzy in Safari under some circumstances

Tags: d3.js, svg, safari, mobile-safari, svg-filters

I have an page with an interactive SVG which looks fine on all browsers (Firefox, Chrome, even IE/Edge) except Safari where everything affected by one of the SVG filters turns into a fuzzy mush (looks like something rendered onto a low-resolution canvas which got scaled up using bilinear interpolation).

Here now a small test case where the problem also appears:

```html
<svg>
  <defs>
    <filter id="filter" y="-100" x="-100" height="300" width="300">
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="3.5"></feGaussianBlur>
      <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="0 0 0 2 0   0 0 0 2 0   0 0 0 0 0   0 0 0 1 0" result="lightenedBlur"></feColorMatrix>
      <feMerge>
        <feMergeNode in="lightenedBlur"></feMergeNode>
        <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"></feMergeNode>
      </feMerge>
    </filter>
  </defs>
  <g>
    <rect x="10" y="10" width="100" height="100" fill="blue" filter="url(#filter)"></rect>
  </g>
</svg>
```

How it looks on Apple Safari 11 (on OS X 10.13):
[image: Apple Safari 11 (on OS X 10.13) showing SVG filter issue]

Compare that to Google Chrome and Mozilla Firefox respectively:
[image: Google Chrome not showing SVG filter issue] [image: Mozilla Firefox not showing SVG filter issue]

When looking at [other SVG filter demo pages on the web](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/feMerge#Result) though the effect apparently isn't there. Not quite sure what exactly causes it. What I noticed is that the issue becomes more apparent the larger the filter area is (controlled through the `width`/`height` attributes of `<filter>`).

Is this a known issue? Under what circumstances does it occur? What are reasonable workarounds?

Comment: Have you noticed that two filter primitives use `result="lightenedBlur"`?

Comment: @ccprog Changed it, makes no difference.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is not a bug. Safari is punishing you for incorrect syntax in your filter declaration:

```
<filter id="filter" y="-100" x="-100" height="300" width="300">
```

According to spec, this should be read as height="30000%" and width="30000%". Safari is saying "ok I guess you meant this" and adjusting the filter resolution automatically so it doesn't allocate a huge piece of memory to this very large buffer -> hence crappy resolution.

If you meant 300% - then you need to put 300%. This is one fix:

```
<filter id="filter" y="-100%" x="-100%" height="300%" width="300%">
```

If you meant 300px (really userSpace units) - then this is another fix:

```
<filter id="filter" y="100" x="-100" height="300" width="300" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
```

You must explicitly tell Safari that you mean pixels by specifying userSpaceOnUse (otherwise it uses the silent default objectBoundingBox)

Another fix - is to over-ride Safari's filter resolution adjustment by explicitly specifying a filterRes. filterRes has been deprecated in the new Filters 1.0 spec and already removed from latest Chrome & Firefox, but Safari still supports it. Since this will result in a big memory hit(and it's hard to believe that you meant to size your filter as you did) - this is not recommended. But whatever - for completeness.

```
<filter id="filter" y="-100" x="-100" height="300" width="300" filterRes="100000">
```

(Two other minor notes - you can make your filters less wordy by using self-closing elements. And the blur adjustment you're doing doesn't lighten the blur, it just dials up the opacity fwiw.)

Comment: You're right, how embarrassing, I guess I assumed for some reason that percentages were the default unit. I guess I could have created some dummy filter just to show me the size. Didn't know about `filterRes`, I wonder if it might be worth reviving for the idea of [automatic filter areas](https://github.com/w3c/fxtf-drafts/issues/2).

Comment: Not embarrassing at all. SVG is much stricter than HTML/CSS on what it's supposed to accept - and Chrome misleads people by accepting bad syntax.